# Unable to import class from one app into another in django

Tags: python, django, python-import, importerror

I am trying to import a class from one Django app inside another Django app.

```
mainProjectFolder
|--__init__.py
|--manage.py
|--app1
    |--__init__.py
    |--class1.py
|--app2
    |--__init__.py
    |--anotherClass.py
|--mainProjectFolder
    |--__init__.py
    |--settings.py
    ...
```

in `app2.anotherClass.py`, I am doing:

```
from mainProjectFolder.app1.class1 import Class1
```

And I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'mainProjectFolder.app1'
```

I have registered my the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file as well.

Please let me know if anything is unclear, I will edit the required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to include project name for import.
If you have all the apps in the same level of hierarchy in the project folder, then just call the files by their app.

Just use:

```
 from app1.class1 import Class1
```

and

```
 from app2.anotherClass import Class2
```

And regarding the error :

```
'unresolved references app1'
```

Use your project folder consisting apps as the **Source Root** then the app will get recognized.

Comment: This is not relative import, I am importing `app1.class1` from `app2.anotherClass`

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog Just use my solution. The name might not be relative import but solution is correct.

Comment: It actually worked, but in PyCharm there is still and Red underling saying 'unresolved references app1'

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog Try refreshing and/or restarting pycharm.

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog And use your project folder consisting apps as the **Source Root** then the app will get recognized.